# Unable to locate element of button facebook login

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, google-chrome, authentication

I want to login to Facebook with Python / Selenium..., it works very good in the beginning, it locate "email" , "password" but for login button no???

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="loginbutton"]"}
(Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)
Thanks a lot guys

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
  
    
usr=input('Entrer un Email valide:') 
pwd=input('Entrer le Mot de Passe:') 
  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
print ("Opened facebook")
sleep(1)
  
username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
username_box.send_keys(usr)
print ("Email Id entered")
sleep(1)
  
password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('pass')
password_box.send_keys(pwd)
print ("Pass entered")
  
login_box = driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton')
login_box.click()
  
print ("OK")
input('Press anything to quit')
driver.quit()
print("Finished")
```

Comment: Please be aware that Facebook does not allow you to interact with their website in any other way then using the API. So if you get banned you know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong locator.
This will work:

```
login_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[name='login']")
```